# Find number of successes from a list of terms/goals

Tags: functional-programming, logic-programming, mercury, functional-logic-progr

I have written the following predicate `exactly/2` that succeeds if exactly `N` of the numbers in the list `L` are equal to 1:

```
:- pred exactly(int, list(int)).
:- mode exactly(in, in) is semidet.
:- mode exactly(out, in) is det.
exactly(N, L) :-
    length(filter(pred(X::in) is semidet :- (X = 1), L), N).
```

For example, the call `exactly(X, [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1])` will bind `X` to `3`.

I want to create something similar, but for predicates: I want to write a predicate that succeeds if exactly `N` goals from the list `L` are successful.

For example, the call `exactly(X, [true, false, member(1, [1, 2, 3]), member(0, [1, 2, 3])])` should bind `X` to `2`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this can be done, as shown by this code:

```
:- module exactly.

:- interface.
:- import_module io.

:- pred main(io::di, io::uo) is det.

:- implementation.

:- import_module int.
:- import_module list.

main(!IO) :-
    Test1 = list_member(1, [1, 2, 3]),
    Test2 = list_member(0, [1, 2, 3]),
    Tests = [Test1, Test2],
    exactly(N, Tests),
    io.write_line(N, !IO).

:- pred exactly(int::out, list((pred))::in(list_skel((pred) is semidet)))
    is det.

exactly(0, []).
exactly(N, [Test | Tests]) :-
    exactly(NTail, Tests),
    ( if Test then
        N = NTail + 1
    else
        N = NTail
    ).

:- pred list_member(T::in, list(T)::in) is semidet.

list_member(E, L) :-
    list.member(E, L).
```

The predicate list_member tells the compiler which mode of
list.member you want to call. As for true and false, you would
need to define predicates of those names as well. (By default,
they exist as goals only.)